# How to correctly structure an appliance?

Tags: java, oop, data-structures, extension-methods

I'm trying to correctly create a class that correctly implements the energy usage of an appliance. This includes the amount of water, gas or electricity it uses along with if the device is switched on or off and finally the amount of time that the device is being used for. When all these factors are correctly implementation, this information will then get passed onto various meters that will calculate the usage of all appliances associated with it.

For now, I have not programmed anything to be outputted, I am still focusing on structuring each appliance so that it can correctly register this information so that it can later be passed onto their respective meters.

The types of information which should be registered are these:

- `useTime()` - Registers the amount of time that the appliance is being used for.
- `currentState()` - If the appliance is on or off.
- Constructor that stores the values of electricity, water and gas use along with the amount of time that the device has been on for.
- Individual appliance actions (such as `cook()` or `shower()`).

This is what I have come up with so far for one of my appliances:

**GasCooker appliance**

```
public class GasCooker extends Cooker
{

    public int isOn = -1;
    public int isOff = 0;
    public int totalTime;
    public int incrementTime;

     @Override
     public int currentState(int x)
    {

        x = -1;
        if (x == 0)
        return isOff;
        else
            return isOn;

        //returns isOn;
}

     @Override
        public void useTime(int defaultTime)
        {

            defaultTime = 15;
            incrementTime = 4;

        }

         public void cook()
         {

             //add code for coker to cook;

         }

   GasCooker(int electricityUse, int gasUse, int waterUse, int timeOn)  
{

    super(electricityUse, gasUse, waterUse, timeOn);
    totalTime = 15 * incrementTime;
    electricityUse = 0 * incrementTime;
    gasUse = 4 * incrementTime;
    waterUse = 0 * incrementTime;
    timeOn = 60 * incrementTime;

} 

}
```

This appliance is a sub class of a `Cooker` class which looks like this:

**Cooker**

```
public abstract class Cooker extends Appliance
{

    public int isOn = -1;
    public int isOff = 0;

     @Override
     public int currentState(int x)
    {

        x = -1;
        if (x == 0)
        return isOff;
        else
            return isOn;

        //returns isOn;
}

     public abstract void cook();

    Cooker(int electricityUse, int gasUse, int waterUse, int timeOn)  
{
    super(electricityUse, gasUse, waterUse, timeOn);
} 

}
```

Which is extended from `Appliance`:

**Appliance**

```
abstract public class Appliance 
{

     public abstract void useTime(int defaultTime);

    public int currentState(int x)
    {
        int timeOn = -1;
        int timeOff = 0;
        x = 0;
        if (x == 0)
        return timeOff;
        else
            return timeOn;
}

Appliance(int electricityUse,int gasUse,int waterUse,int timeOn) 
{
    electricityUse = 0;
    gasUse = 0;
    waterUse = 0;
    timeOn = 0; 
}

}
```

The main queries that I have are these:

- Do these classes look like sensible classes for registering this information?
- If not, in which part have I misconceived?

This is my first assignment in which I have to define my own methods so any feedback on the sensibility of my program so far or how it could be improved would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Yes I don't see anything extremely glaring but this isn't really a great question because it is relatively subjective. What some consider good others might consider bad. That being said this is a good start! Keep up the good work!

Comment: You might want to look at the code review stackexchange instead; there are many errors in your code, ignoring method parameter values, unreachable statements etc.